# Getting weeks from timestamp which spans more than a year in R

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset containing a series of time stamps from `01/01/2015` to `01/01/2017` `(dd/mm/yyyy)`. I want to convert it to Weeks (i.e) `01/01/2015` Week 0, `08/01/2015` becomes Week 1 ... `01/01/2017` should become Week 104 (or something around this number).

I tried the following method

```
> sD
  "2016-04-13 05:30:00 IST" "2017-04-10 05:30:00 IST"
> format(as.Date(sD,format = guess_formats(sD,c('dmy'))), "%W")
     "15" "15"
```

Here for the same date but for different years I am getting the same Week. I need the output to change with year also. How to go about doing this?

Comment: and I found a math hack : `as.numeric(format(sD,"%U")) + ((as.numeric(format(sD, "%Y")) - 2015) * 52)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the difference and specify the unit as weeks:

```
x <- as.Date(c("2015-01-01","2015-01-08","2017-01-01"))
difftime(x, as.Date("2015-01-01"), units="weeks")
#Time differences in weeks
#[1]   0.0000   1.0000 104.4286
```